# crash on shader link

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a fatal signal at the time of glLink(..)

```
afficheurShader = GLES30.glCreateProgram();        
GLES30.glAttachShader(afficheurShader, afficheurVertex);  
GLES30.glAttachShader(afficheurShader, afficheurFragment)
GLES30.glLinkProgram(afficheurShader);
```

> > > > > Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1...

afficheurShader.vert :

```
#version 300 es

precision highp float;
precision highp sampler2D;
precision highp int;

layout(location = 0) in uvec2 position;
layout(location = 1) in uint couleur;
uniform  sampler2D pvTex;
uniform vec2 resolution;
flat out uint vCouleur;

void main() {
    vCouleur = couleur;
    ivec2 ipos = ivec2(position);

    vec4 pos4 = texelFetch(pvTex, ipos,0);  // THIS LINE MAKE CRASH

    gl_Position = vec4(pos4.xy,0.0,1.0);
}
```

If i comment the line with texelFetch,  there is no crash :

```
    //vec4 pos4 = texelFetch(pvTex, ipos,0);  // THIS LINE MAKE CRASH
    vec4 pos4 = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
```

So i guess the problem is with "texelFetch"...but what is wrong with my syntax ?

EDIT :

I use Android Studio and the problem occurs when I run the project on my tablet. BUT no problem when I do the same thing with my phone connected.

EDIT 2 :

IT SEEMS THAT THE PROBLEM COMES FROM THE FRAGMENT !!

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;
flat in uint vCouleur;
uniform uint cols[256];
out vec4 outputColor;
void main() {
    int indbase = int(vCouleur*3u);
    float r = float(cols[indbase]);
    float v = float(cols[indbase+1]);
    float b = float(cols[indbase+2]);
    outputColor = vec4( r ,v,b,255.0)/255.0;
}
```

I left the texelfetch untouched in the vertex, but in the fragment I commented on the calls to the array:

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;
flat in uint vCouleur;
uniform uint cols[256];
out vec4 outputColor;
void main() {
    int indbase = int(vCouleur*3u);
    //float r = float(cols[indbase]);
    //float v = float(cols[indbase+1]);
    //float b = float(cols[indbase+2]);
    float r= 255.0; ///
    float v= 255.0; /// DEBUG TEMPORARY SOLUTION
    float b= 255.0; ///
    outputColor = vec4( r ,v,b,255.0)/255.0;
}
```

AND NO CRASH ! (ok , it is all white pixel...)

So, the problem comes from :

```
cols[indbase]
```

Comment: Are you checking for errors in shader compilation?

Comment: @Columbo, yes  glGetShaderiv(afficheurVertex, GLES30.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0); compileStatus is empty string, and  glGetShaderiv(afficheurFragment, GLES30.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0); compileStatus is empty string.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty this looks like a driver bug.

OpenGL ES drivers shouldn't crash unless the application passes in bad pointers; you should always get an cleanly thrown error. What is the tablet / GPU with the problem?

Comment: Sony Xperia Z3 Tablet Compact SGP611

Comment: The GPU is an Adreno 330 - you might get some help for a workaround asking on the Qualcomm developer forums.

Answer (score -1):

i put all the code with cols from fragment to vertex.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf

In the vertex shader, support for all forms of array indexing is mandated. In the fragment shader, support for indexing is only mandated for constant-index-expressions.

and it's work !